# How can i get Cesium to work with a flexbox layout?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, cesiumjs

I have an example of the layout I am going for in [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucastheisen/cpqfhws5/5/).

If you run that fiddle and click the `Leaflet` button, everything works great (*works great with google too, but I cant post my api key*).

If you click `Cesium`, it does not seem to respect the flexbox space allotted to it.  Any idea how to get Cesium to behave?

***Note, you may have to resize your browser a bit to show the problem***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of some strangeness with flexbox attempting to preserve the canvas' aspect ratio (needlessly, in the case of Cesium, because it will just rerender on the next frame).

Here's a workaround.  Edit the top of your jsFiddle CSS to look like this:

```css
  html {
      height: 100%;
  }
  #cesiumContainer, .leaflet-container {
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
```

Then, add one new rule to your existing `.app .data .map` block:

```css
  .app .data .map {
      /* keep existing rules here */
      position: relative;
  }
```

Here's the [modified jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4fbhLvj/1/).

This sets up a parent/child relationship, where the parent flexbox element has gained a `position: relative`, which means that any "absolute" children of it will be absolutely positioned within its coordinates (making them effectively relative to it).  The child in this case is `#cesiumContainer`, which we have now positioned absolutely, not so much to gain the absolute nature of the coordinate system, merely to gain the side effect that the sizes of absolutely-positioned elements don't contribute to the document flow around them.  This means that Cesium's `canvas` element can't push flexbox around, it must conform to it exactly, which is what we want.

Comment: Thank you!  This was driving me nuts!